# REST uri calls using get

Tags: jquery

Stupid questions I guess but how do I do a REST uri call. Do I use jquery ajax() or just plain $get()
All the REST uri does is return an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `$.get`, it's a shortcut of `$.ajax` and would be well suited in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a REST resource is exactly the same as navigating to it in a browser.  Are you going to display the image?  The easiest thing to do would be to set the img src property to the resource URL

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` function is just a small wrapper for `ajax()`, so either one should work. The `ajax()` function allows more options, but the `get()` function is great for simple requests.

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm assuming you're passing some variable with the Get to specify a dynamic image.  Do a `$.get` like you suspect, but in the header of the response, set it as an image.  php example:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

If this isn't a dynamic image, just statically link to it in the `img` tag.